# buffered read write same file in go

Tags: go

I am trying to read a very large file line by line and the replace something in line and write back to same file. I am not able to find a way to do that.
Currently I have created a temp file and save the replaced line in temp file and at last copy the temp file content in original file. But I have to do two reads and two writes. I want to avoid that. Any ideas.

below is what I have tried:

```
file, _ := os.Open("somelargesay1GbFile.txt")
defer file.Close()

outFile, _ := os.OpenFile("temp.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0777)
defer outFile.Close()

reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(file, 10*1024)

for {
    bytesread, isprefix, err := reader.ReadLine()

    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {

            data := changeTheData(string(bytesread))

            outFile.WriteString(data)

            if !isprefix {
                outFile.WriteString("\r\n")
            }
        } else {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        break
    }

    data := changeTheData(string(bytesread))
    outFile.WriteString(data)
    if !isprefix {
        outFile.WriteString("\r\n")
    }
}
```

Finally I delete the file `somelargesay1GbFile.txt` and rename it to `temp.txt`

Comment: Just rename the temp file instead of copying.

Comment: Has the data you replace the same byte length as the new data ? If yes, you could indeed overwrite the data. Otherwise you can't avoid creating the new file.

Comment: There are some more complexities like concurrency and all. SO I can not keep deleting and renaming

Comment: @chmike yes data will of same length after replacing. But still how do I write back to same file

Comment: to answer your question, you got to explain and demonstrate what `changeTheData` is performing.

Comment: "I am not able to find a way to do that." Yes, simply because this is not possible. In general you cannot "change" the middle of a file.

Comment: @Volker but you can overwrite the data in the middle of a file

Comment: @chmike You must read carefully: "In general"! If you are dealing with fixed sized records of course you can overwrite a record. But in general---read "non fixed sized records" (and the file extension of ".txt" hints at this) you cannot and that is what I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to open the file twice, first for reading and second for overwriting the content.

See the code below.

Note that I use `reader.ReadString('\n')`instead of `ReadLine`. Note also that I write to the output before testing the error. This is because the last line that is not ended by '\n' is returned together with the `io.EOF`error.

```golang
func main() {
    inFile, _ := os.Open("file.txt")
    defer inFile.Close()

    outFile, _ := os.OpenFile("file.txt", os.O_RDWR, 0777)
    defer outFile.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(inFile, 10*1024)

    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        outFile.WriteString(changeData(line))
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("error:", err)
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the code with this `changeData`function that change lower case letters to upper case letters, and upper case letters to lower case letters. We can then test the changes by calling the functions repeatedly.

```golang
func changeData(data string) string {
    o := make([]rune, 0, len(data))
    for _, r := range data {
        if unicode.IsLetter(r) {
            if unicode.IsUpper(r) {
                o = append(o, unicode.ToLower(r))
            } else {
                o = append(o, unicode.ToUpper(r))
            }
        } else {
            o = append(o, r)
        }
    }
    return string(o)
}
```

This code will overwrite every line of the file. Whether the line is modified depends on what `changeData`does.

If you want to avoid overwriting every lines because, for instance, most lines don't need to be changed, you then have to seek to the location you want to overwrite data.